# Can _mget retrieve by non-ID field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to look-up multiple users by e-mail address in ES (as well as report which ones are NOT found) from my limited (as in 2 days old) knowledge of ES this sounds like a natural fit for the mget operation?

However according to the documentation it appears that mget only supports retrieval by the ID field? Is there anyway to use mget in conjunction with another field, eg e-mail? The field is also a nested field (eg nested_object.email)

Is it possible to tell mget to use another field? Is there a better query type better-suited for this requirement (including reporting which search terms failed) ?

Comment: can you post your full mappings and one sample document?

Comment: Certainly, please find it here https://jsfiddle.net/sjohbdss/ the field I want to retrieve by is rm_data.rm_email
Sample document: https://jsfiddle.net/h7j77zsc/

Comment: You're probably looking for `_msearch` aka [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Comment: Great thanks Val - that works too! Just out of curiosity, if I'm simply looking up on a non-analyzed, exact value field - is it desirable to use a filter-based query for each search item in the multi-search payload (I read filters are faster and cacheable) vs a match-based query on that field? Also, guessing _mget only works on the ID field (also, please leave an answer so I can give credit appropriately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `_msearch` endpoint, aka [the multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html). It allows you to send multiple searches in one shot, e.g.

```
$ cat requests
{"index" : "users"}
{"query" : {"term" : {"email":"name1@server.com"}}}
{"index" : "users"}
{"query" : {"term" : {"email":"name2@server.com"}}}
{"index" : "users"}
{"query" : {"term" : {"email":"name3@server.com"}}}
{"index" : "users"}
{"query" : {"term" : {"email":"name4@server.com"}}}

$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch --data-binary "@requests"; echo
```

To answer your other question in the comments, it depends on whether you are using a pre-2.0 ES release or not. Before ES 2.0, queries and filters differed in the way you describe (filters were faster and cachable and did not participate in the scoring). As of 2.0, [queries and filters have been merged](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_queries_and_filters_merged) ([the full story is here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0)) and queries can also be used in filters and vice versa. There's still a filter context which you can use when you don't need scoring but want your filters to be cacheable. The execution will be automatically optimized by ES to run in the most efficient order possible.

Oh, and yes, `_mget` only works with IDs.